# Add Arabic Abstract at the end of a document

Tags: arabic, abstract

I am using this  [template](https://github.com/kks32/phd-thesis-template/) for my master's thesis; however, I can not add the Arabic language to the output.

Is there any way to add an Arabic abstract at the end of the document?

P.S: I am using LaTeX.

Comment: You’re not giving us enough information: that template is said to work with LaTeX, XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX, and we need to know which of those you’re using, because the methods available for working with Arabic differ accordingly.

Comment: @Thérèse Thank you for your comment
I am using LaTeX

Comment: Two more questions:  Is English the main language of your thesis, with Arabic only in the abstract?  Is it OK to put the abstract before the table of contents, as shown in the template, or do you really want the abstract at the end?  (Would the university accept placement of the abstract at the end?)

Comment: @Thérèse 
Yes English is my main language 
in my university we have to submit the thesis with two abstracts; one in English in its original position and the other one which is the Arabic Abstract at the end of the document 
So we end up having two abstracts in the document

Comment: And also i'd like to change the abstract title for the arabic abstract to (ملخص)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a thesis in English with a second abstract in Arabic, here is a way to use the template:

1. In `preamble.tex`, add `\usepackage{arabtex,utf8}` at the end of the file.
2. In the “Abstract” directory, create a file called `secondabstract.tex`, which should look something like this:

   ```
   \cleardoublepage% copied from .cls file’s definition of abstract
   \setsinglecolumn% copied from .cls file
   \setcode{utf8}
   \setarab
   \chapter*{\centering\Large\RL{ملخص}}% copied from .cls file
   \thispagestyle{empty}% copied from .cls file
   \begin{RLtext}
     أحب القراءة كثيرا‬
   \end{RLtext}
   ```
3. `thesis.tex` will look something like this:

   ```
   \documentclass[a5paper,11pt,times,numbered,print,index]{Classes/PhDThesisPSnPDF}
   \input{Preamble/preamble}
   \input{thesis-info}
   \begin{document}
   \frontmatter
   \maketitle
   \include{Dedication/dedication}
   \include{Declaration/declaration}
   \include{Acknowledgement/acknowledgement}
   \include{Abstract/abstract}% here’s your English abstract
   \tableofcontents
   \listoffigures
   \listoftables
   \printnomenclature
   \mainmatter
   \include{Chapter1/chapter1}

   \backmatter

   \begin{spacing}{0.9}
   \bibliographystyle{apalike}
   \cleardoublepage
   \bibliography{References/references}
   \end{spacing}

   \printthesisindex
   \include{Abstract/secondabstract}% here’s your Arabic abstract
   \end{document}
   ```
4. Compile with `latexmk -pdf thesis.tex`

I assume that you prefer to type Arabic directly; you can also use the `arabtex` system of transliteration, in which case you would omit `utf8` from the packages loaded in the preamble, and `\setcode{utf8}` from `abstract.tex`.

Comment: No i have an English Abstract already
I need to add another abstract in arabic 
So i end up having two abstracts
The one in english in its original position and the arabic abstract at the end of the document

Comment: I’ve replaced my original answer in light of your comment; does this one address your needs?

Comment: Yes, Thank you!
I have accepted this as the answer